# Django Multiple paypal IPN signals received

Tags: django, paypal

We are using django-paypal for paypal ipn notification.

All works great signals are received and inserted in the ipn tables .
We have specified the IPN URL in merchant profile. When you check the history logs of paypal ipn it says retrying ... times even though our server is receiving each signal

We even wrote to paypal regarding this but they say they are not getting http status code 200 from our server.

What could be the issue when all signals are successfully inserted into our database.Each purchase has atleast 10 entries which is number of times paypal tries to send if it doesnt get 200 status

Any help to fix this is much appreciated

Comment: Check your error logs. They'll tell you what response code you're returning. Then check the error logs again to find out why that is

Comment: If the problem remains please show IPN view code

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed.

After saving the object (ipn) it should return HttpResponse("OKAY") to paypal
but somehow my code had an empty return